# Change color of scroll buttons in MenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

[image]

The problem is that I didn't find colors in `ProfessionalColorTable` for buttons which scroll very long `DropDown` `MenuItem`. So how can I change colors of this buttons?